# Looking for a program to view Windows messages

Tags: windows, windows-messages

I am looking for a program to view Windows messages

Can you help?

Answer (score 5):

Spy++ comes with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

I have found [Winspector](http://www.windows-spy.com/) to be somewhat more stable than Spy++ especially while debugging a program while at the same time monitoring messages.

Comment: Unfortunately Winspector seems to have problems with Windows 7 :( On my system it lags and slows down the whole system, being unresponsive for longer periods of time.